# VueJS: How to access parameter value inside routes file

Tags: vue.js, routes, store

I'm having this route in routes.js

```
{
 path: "/dashboard/:user_id?/:entity_id?/:server_id?",
 name: "Dashboard",
 component: () => import("./views/dashboard"),
 meta: {
   authRequired: true,
 },
},
```

If user isn't logged in, he will get redirected to the login page but before that I want to check if parameter is already set (user_id for example) and store it before going to the login page. How can I do that inside routes.js file inside this path?

Comment: Which parameter did you mean?

Comment: user_id, server_id ..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a guard that checks if the user is logged in called `authenticationGuard` you could do something like:

```
export function authenticationGuard(to, from) {
  if (to.params.user_id) {
    // do whatever you would like with `user_id` here
  }
}
```

If you dont control the the `authenticationGuard` you can insert the routeGuard in the route itself:

```
{
 path: "/dashboard/:user_id?/:entity_id?/:server_id?",
 name: "Dashboard",
 component: () => import("./views/dashboard"),
 meta: {
   authRequired: true,
 },
 beforeEnter: (to, from) {
   if (to.params.user_id) {
     // do whatever you would like with user_id here
   }
 }
},
```